# What is wrong with this batch file?

Tags: batch-file, wix

I need to include all the file dependencies in my Wix project and it is a pain to do it manually. So I searched the site and found this batch file. I follow the steps but got the errors. What the batch file does is scan all the projects and generate a wxs file.

```
  @echo off
  set SOLUTIONDIR=%1
  set OUTPUTFILE=%2
  echo Starting Dependency check...
  echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?^> > %OUTPUTFILE%
  echo ^<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
  echo   ^<Fragment^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
  echo     ^<ComponentGroup Id="MesDependance" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%

  for %%F in (%SOLUTIONDIR%ClientSetup\bin\Debug\*.dll) do (
  echo "-- Adding %%~nxF" 
  echo       ^<Component Id="%%~nF"^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
  echo     ^<File  Id="%%~nF" Name="%%~nxF" Source="%%~dpnxF" Vital="yes"          KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
  echo       ^</Component^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
   )
  echo     ^</ComponentGroup^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
  echo   ^</Fragment^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
  echo ^</Wix^> >> %OUTPUTFILE%
  echo Dependency check done.
```

Comment: The error is Error 104 The command "call "C:\ForInstaller\EasyLobby VMS 11\ClientConfigurationUtil\GenerateDependency.bat" "C:\ForInstaller\EasyLobby VMS 11\" "C:\ForInstaller\EasyLobby VMS 11\ClientConfigurationUtil\Dependencies.wxs"" exited with code 1. ClientConfigurationUtil

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are the spaces. As a general rule, all paths should be quoted (just in case it have spaces), the content in the variables should not have quotes (it is harder to remove them than to add when needed) and when a path is constructed from the variable content, quote the resulting path

```
 @echo off
    set "SOLUTIONDIR=%~1"
    set "OUTPUTFILE=%~2"
```

Values retrieved without quotes, stored in variables without quotes. Quotes in `set` command ensure the content is properly stored with no aditional spaces added

```
    echo Starting Dependency check...
    (   echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?^> 
        echo ^<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"^>
        echo   ^<Fragment^>
        echo     ^<ComponentGroup Id="MesDependance" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"^>
    )> "%OUTPUTFILE%"

    for %%F in ("%SOLUTIONDIR%ClientSetup\bin\Debug\*.dll") do (
        echo -- Adding %%~nxF
        (   echo        ^<Component Id="%%~nF"^> 
            echo            ^<File  Id="%%~nF" Name="%%~nxF" Source="%%~dpnxF" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/^> 
            echo        ^</Component^> 
        ) >> "%OUTPUTFILE%"
    )

    (   echo     ^</ComponentGroup^> 
        echo   ^</Fragment^> 
        echo ^</Wix^> 
    ) >> "%OUTPUTFILE%"

    echo Dependency check done.
```

All references to files, both in redirections and inside `for in(` are properly quoted to ensure there are no problems with spaces.